# Can the idiom "make it fast/quick" replace "be brief"?

Tags: idioms

Example:

> The story is kinda long. But don't worry, I'll try to be brief/make it fast.

Does it sound weird to use *make it fast* instead of *to be brief*? And why?

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be "weird" - weird is when you see a ghost. "Time's short, I'll make it quick" - nothing wrong with that, it's perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: Note that "make it fast" has an entirely different meaning in a nautical context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about rephrasing the sentence?
*"The story is kinda long, but don't worry, I'll tell it in brief"*
(I'll say what I have to say in very few words).

Although *I'll try to be brief* option is also correct.

1. **In brief**

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-brief

in brief:

If you refer to something in brief, you are referring to a shortened version of it with few details.
*...and now sport in brief*.

Synonyms: briefly, in summary, in synopsis, in digest form

in brief:

You can say in brief to indicate that you are about to say something in as few words as possible or to give a summary of what you have just said.
*In brief, take no risks.*

Synonyms: in short, briefly, in essence, in a word

in brief in British:
in short; to sum up

in brief in American:
in short; in a few words

2. **Make it fast**

I would use *make it fast* for other example sentences rather than for this one: *I know you don't have much time, so I'll try to make it fast*

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/make-it-quick-fast

make it quick/fast:
​
uk informal make it snappy used to tell someone to do something quickly or to hurry up:

*Take him to the hospital - and make it quick!*